# Redemption: Error when using Task Scheduler

Tags: exchange-server, mapi, outlook-redemption

I use a self written tool that uses Outlook Redemption to do some sync between our own data and a some user's calendars on Office365. When running the tool under the admin account on a Windows server, it works perfectly. When running it as a scheduled task under that same account, it does not. It says:

> Error in
> IMAPISession::OpenMsgStore(pbExchangeProviderPrimaryUserGuid):
> MAPI_E_LOGON_FAILED

Any suggestions?

Comment: If your mailbox is OAuth (as opposed to Basic Auth), the auth tokens cannot be shared between apps running in different security contexts - note that Task Scheduler runs in a different context even if the local user is the same.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How can I solve this? Do I need to change settings on the Exchange accounts? Or is there another solution?

Comment: I don't think there is anything you can do...

Comment: You wrote about OAuth as opposed to Basic Auth. Is this a setting, can you choose between the 2, or is OAuth inherent to Office365?

Comment: It is a settings set by the Exchange admin.

Comment: See [Account setup with modern authentication in Exchange Online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/outlook-for-ios-and-android/setup-with-modern-authentication)